# When do I include a new roof on my taxes if contract and install are in different years?

Tags: united-states, taxes

In California, USA, in October of 2022 I signed a contract, paid a deposit, and began making payments (10 year term) on a new roof for an investment property.

The unusually stormy season has delayed installation of that roof until April 2023.

In which year do I report the capital improvement of the roof?

When I contracted/paid for it in 2022? Or when it actually enters service on the property in 2023?
Or perhaps less likely, when I finish paying it off in 2032?

Note: you may see my other, similar question about the solar panels. I split them into separate questions because I suspect the answers are different and future searches may benefit from finding them independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The year placed in service. See [instructions to form 4562](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i4562#en_US_2022_publink1000309317).